# Location for scheduled tasks in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

I need to build a few tasks that import various data from outside APIs in my SailsJS project.  I was thinking of using laterJS (unless there's a better option).

Is there a best practice for the location and loading of these "task" files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where I think it should go is file config/bootstrap.js.

Description of this file from sails-docs:

> This is an asynchronous boostrap function that runs before your Sails app gets lifted (i.e. > starts up). This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model, run jobs, or perform 
>   some special logic.

Comment: Hi Pawel, have you a sample ?